# How to reset length of `ScrollView` text?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I'm displaying some text with a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`. The activity changes the text (when user hits nav arrow), but the `ScrollView` doesn't alter its height for changed text length. As a result, it won't scroll down all the way down for text longer than the original.

**To be clear**, I don't want the views to lengthen on the screen, but just the scrollable length to lengthen (or shorten). Btw, what is the name of this attribute?

Here's one attempt:

```
    ScrollView vscr = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    vscr.requestLayout();
```

I've also tried `vscr.computeScroll();` and `vscr.recomputeViewAttributes(findViewById(R.id.content));`, though maybe I'm using them wrongly (I'm rather new at this).

Can anyone tell me how to get the `ScrollView` to lengthen itself when the contained text becomes longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did  you set the height of your layouts to wrap_content?

Comment: That did it! I had that attribute set for the `ScrollView`, but not the `TextView`. Thanks, Xenione. Excellent!

Comment: P.S. Do you know the name of the attribute? Maybe something like ScrollLength or ScrollMaxY?

Comment: try this .getHeight() I thinks it's the same as every layout.

Comment: @JohnK If the answer provided fixed your problem, accept answer. Cheers

Comment: @SathishJayapal: Patience, my friend. The speed of the internet fuels an expectation of instant closure.